# How to fix my Cordova file?

Tags: javascript, css, html, cordova

I have been trying to save a photo the timestamp and the location into a file which I need to call data.bin. I try following the [cordova plugin file site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file#persistent) but I had no success. Does any one have any suggestion what I can do? Here is my code:

## Meta Tags

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1"> -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=2"> -->
```

## Css

```
/* following three (cascaded) are equivalent to above three meta viewport statements */
/* see http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2014/05/html5_dev_conf.html */
/* see http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/ */
@-ms-viewport { width: 100vw ; min-zoom: 100% ; zoom: 100% ; }
@viewport { width: 100vw ; min-zoom: 100% zoom: 100% ; }
@-ms-viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; min-zoom: 100% ; }
@viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; min-zoom: 100% ; }
/*@-ms-viewport { user-zoom: zoom ; min-zoom: 100% ; max-zoom: 200% ; }   @viewport { user-zoom: zoom ; min-zoom: 100% ; max-zoom: 200% ; }*/
```

## JS

```
    var todayDate = new Date();
    var imgLocation = getLocaleName();
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
      navigator.splashscreen.show();
      setTimeout(function(){ navigator.splashscreen.hide(); }, 3000);
      pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
      destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
      document.getElementById("getLocaleName").addEventListener("click", getLocaleName);   
    }

    window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 5 * 1024 * 1024, function (fs) {
      console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);
      createFile(fs.root, "newTempFile.txt", false);
    }, onErrorLoadFs);
    function createFile(dirEntry, fileName, isAppend) {
    // Creates a new file or returns the file if it already exists. 
        dirEntry.getFile(fileName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) {
          writeFile(fileEntry, null, isAppend);
        }, onErrorCreateFile);
     }
     function writeFile(fileEntry, dataObj) {
        // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt). 
        fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {

        fileWriter.onwriteend = function() {
        console.log("Successful file write...");
        readFile(fileEntry);
     };

        fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
        console.log("Failed file write: " + e.toString());
    };

    // If data object is not passed in, 
    // create a new Blob instead. 
    if (!dataObj) {
        dataObj = new Blob(['some file data'], { type: 'text/plain' });
    }

    fileWriter.write(dataObj);
  });
}
function readFile(fileEntry) {

  fileEntry.file(function (file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function() {
        console.log("Successful file read: " + this.result);
        displayFileData(fileEntry.fullPath + ": " + this.result);
    };

    reader.readAsText(file);

  }, onErrorReadFile);
}



window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function (dirEntry) {
  console.log('file system open: ' + dirEntry.name);
  var isAppend = true;
  createFile(dirEntry, "fileToAppend.txt", isAppend);
}, onErrorLoadFs);



function writeFile(fileEntry, dataObj, isAppend) {
// Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt). 
  fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
    fileWriter.onwriteend = function() {
        console.log("Successful file write...");
        if (dataObj.type == "image/png") {
            readBinaryFile(fileEntry);
        }
        else {
            readFile(fileEntry);
        }
      };

      fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log("Failed file write: " + e.toString());
      };

    fileWriter.write(dataObj);
  });
}
function readBinaryFile(fileEntry) {
  fileEntry.file(function (file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function() {

        console.log("Successful file write: " + this.result);
        displayFileData(fileEntry.fullPath + ": " + this.result);

        var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(this.result)], { type:   "image/png" });
        displayImage(blob);
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

       }, onErrorReadFile);
     }



function displayImage(blob) {

  // Displays image if result is a valid DOM string for an image. 
  var elem = document.getElementById('imageFile');
  // Note: Use window.URL.revokeObjectURL when finished with image. 
  elem.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}


function displayImageByFileURL(fileEntry) {
  var elem = document.getElementById('imageFile');
  elem.src = fileEntry.toURL();
}
```

## HTML

```
<div class="upage" id="mainpage">
   <div class="upage-outer">
        <div class="uib-header header-bg container-group inner-element uib_w_19" data-uib="layout/header" data-ver="0" id="headerMenu">
            <h2>Main Menu</h2>
            <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
            <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left"></div>
            <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="upage-content ac0 content-area vertical-col left" id="page_87_98">
            <div class="list-group widget uib_w_1 d-margins" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_group" data-ver="1">
                <a class="list-group-item allow-badge widget uib_w_2" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_item" data-ver="1"><span class="badge"></span>
                <p class="list-group-item-text list" onclick="takepicture()">Camera</p></a> <a class="list-group-item allow-badge widget uib_w_3" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_item" data-ver="1"><span class="badge"></span>
                <p class="list-group-item-text list">Gallery</p></a> <a class="list-group-item allow-badge widget uib_w_4" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_item" data-ver="1"><span class="badge glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span>
                <p class="list-group-item-text list">Settings</p></a> <a class="list-group-item allow-badge widget uib_w_16 d-margins" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_item" data-ver="1">
                <p class="list-group-item-text list" onclick="exitApplicationPressed()">Exit Application</p></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="upage hidden" id="Settings">
    <div class="upage-outer">
        <div class="uib-header header-bg container-group inner-element uib_w_10" data-uib="layout/header" data-ver="0" id="headerSettings">
            <h2>Settings</h2>
            <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
            <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left">
                <button class="btn widget uib_w_11 d-margins btn-default" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button" data-ver="1" id="Setting-Back">Back</button>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="upage-content ac0 content-area vertical-col left" id="page_79_75">
            <div class="list-group widget uib_w_12 d-margins" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_group" data-ver="1">
                <a class="list-group-item allow-badge widget uib_w_13" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_item" data-ver="1">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Delete Stored Data</p></a> <a class="list-group-item allow-badge widget uib_w_14" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_item" data-ver="1">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Change Theme</p></a> <a class="list-group-item allow-badge widget uib_w_15" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_item" data-ver="1">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Heading</h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text">List item</p></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="upage hidden" id="gallery">
    <div class="upage-outer">
        <div class="uib-header header-bg container-group inner-element uib_w_8" data-uib="layout/header" data-ver="0" id="headerGallery">
            <h2>Gallery</h2>
            <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
            <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left">
                <button class="btn widget uib_w_7 d-margins btn-default" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button" data-ver="1" id="Gallery-Back">back</button>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right">
                <button class="btn widget uib_w_9 d-margins btn-default" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button" data-ver="1">Camera</button>
            </div>
        </div><img id="smallImage" src="" style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;">
        <p id="time"></p>
        <p id="local"></p>
        <div class="upage-content ac0 content-area vertical-col left" id="page_80_76"></div><!--    div-->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="upage hidden" id="Camera">
    <div class="upage-outer">
        <div class="uib-header header-bg container-group inner-element uib_w_26" data-uib="layout/header" data-ver="0">
            <h2>Camera</h2>
            <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
            <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left">
                <button class="btn widget uib_w_27 d-margins btn-default" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button" data-ver="1" id="cBack">Back</button>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right"></div>
        </div><button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button><br>
        <button onclick="onSuccess();">Capture Editable Photo</button><br>
        <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
        <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
        <img id="largeImage" src="" style="display:none;">
        <div class="upage-content ac0 content-area vertical-col left" id="page_71_45"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="upage hidden" id="Theme">
    <div class="upage-outer">
        <div class="uib-header header-bg container-group inner-element uib_w_28" data-uib="layout/header" data-ver="0" id="headerTheme">
            <h2>Theme</h2>
            <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
            <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left">
                <button class="btn widget uib_w_29 d-margins btn-default" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button" data-ver="1" id="TBack">Back</button>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="upage-content ac0 content-area vertical-col left" id="page_30_29">
            <div class="list-group widget uib_w_30 d-margins" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_group" data-ver="1">
                <a class="list-group-item allow-badge widget uib_w_31" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_item" data-ver="1">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" onclick="red()">Red theme</h4></a> <a class="list-group-item allow-badge widget uib_w_32" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_item" data-ver="1">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" onclick="blue()">Blue Theme</h4></a> <a class="list-group-item allow-badge widget uib_w_33" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_item" data-ver="1">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" onclick="green()">Green Theme</h4></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Next time please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).